# How to put separator among variables in R mlogit package

Tags: mlogit

I really appreciate your help with my data.

I am using mlogit package in R for random utility model: [https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v095i11#:~:text=mlogit%20is%20a%20package%20for,random%20parameter%20models](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v095i11#:%7E:text=mlogit%20is%20a%20package%20for,random%20parameter%20models))%20are%20implemented.

The dependent variable "choice" of provinces depends on alternative specific variables: logPCI, logopenness, loglabour3, logunem1, loglabour3 and 4 other variables: logMAinside1, logMAoutside1, logSAinside1, logSAoutside1.

I have a question regarding 4 variables: logMAinside1, logMAoutside1, logSAinside1, logSAoutside1. Are they alternative specific variables or individual specific variables? Firms belonging to the same "sector" in the same province will have the same values of these 4 variables (for example, firm id 108582716 and firm id 108594870 in sample dataset). If firms belonging to the same sector but in different provinces will have different values of these four variables. In another words, the values of these four variables vary by sector and by provinces (alternative). How can I put separator to account for this information?  I read manual of mlogit package in R but do not know how to appy for my data.  Am I correct when I use separator (|) like this?
ml.mydata<- mlogit(choice ~ logPCI + logopenness + logseaport3 + loglabour3 + logunem1| logMAinside1 + logMAoutside1 + logSAinside1 + logSAoutside1, mydata, reflevel = "Hanoi_city").

Here is my sample data set.

```
  structure(
    list(
      firm_id = c(
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108595095,
        108595095,
        108595095,
        108605233,
        108605233,
        108605233,
        201761149,
        201761149,
        201761149,
        201762784,
        201762784,
        201762784,
        201764559,
        201764559,
        201764559
      ),
      alt = c(
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Phutho_province",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Phutho_province",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Phutho_province",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Phutho_province",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Phutho_province",
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Phutho_province",
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Phutho_province"
      ),
      choice = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
                 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
      year_operation = c(
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2017,
        2017,
        2017,
        2017,
        2017,
        2017,
        2017,
        2017,
        2017
      ),
      sector = c(
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SB",
        "SB",
        "SB",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "SM",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SN",
        "SN",
        "SN",
        "SD",
        "SD",
        "SD"
      ),
      technology = c(
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "High",
        "High",
        "High",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "High",
        "High",
        "High",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low"
      ),
      logMAinside1 = c(
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.0093489,
        8.0093489,
        8.0093489,
        8.2393103,
        8.2393103,
        8.2393103,
        6.7310853,
        6.7310853,
        6.7310853,
        8.9314318,
        8.9314318,
        8.9314318,
        7.2551007,
        7.2551007,
        7.2551007
      ),
      logMAoutside1 = c(
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.2819128,
        8.2819128,
        8.2819128,
        9.70644,
        9.70644,
        9.70644,
        8.0759678,
        8.0759678,
        8.0759678,
        8.5643978,
        8.5643978,
        8.5643978,
        7.8877192,
        7.8877192,
        7.8877192
      ),
      logSAinside1 = c(
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.93539,
        7.93539,
        7.93539,
        11.101022,
        11.101022,
        11.101022,
        6.561851,
        6.561851,
        6.561851,
        11.221056,
        11.221056,
        11.221056,
        9.6826878,
        9.6826878,
        9.6826878
      ),
      logSAoutside1 = c(
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        8.2279396,
        8.2279396,
        8.2279396,
        9.4778214,
        9.4778214,
        9.4778214,
        7.7405944,
        7.7405944,
        7.7405944,
        8.3962173,
        8.3962173,
        8.3962173,
        8.0652342,
        8.0652342,
        8.0652342
      ),
      logseaport3 = c(
        1.4350846,
        5.3082676,
        4.8202815,
        1.4350846,
        5.3082676,
        4.8202815,
        1.4350846,
        5.3082676,
        4.8202815,
        1.4350846,
        5.3082676,
        4.8202815,
        4.8202815,
        1.4350846,
        5.3082676,
        1.4350846,
        4.8202815,
        5.3082676,
        1.4350846,
        4.8202815,
        5.3082676
      ),
      logpop = c(
        7.161622,
        5.9839363,
        7.7137847,
        7.161622,
        5.9839363,
        7.7137847,
        7.161622,
        5.9839363,
        7.7137847,
        7.161622,
        5.9839363,
        7.7137847,
        7.6879973,
        7.145196,
        5.9687076,
        7.145196,
        7.6879973,
        5.9687076,
        7.145196,
        7.6879973,
        5.9687076
      ),
      logopenness = c(
        5.5514636,
        4.7599664,
        4.702239,
        5.5514636,
        4.7599664,
        4.702239,
        5.5514636,
        4.7599664,
        4.702239,
        5.5514636,
        4.7599664,
        4.702239,
        4.8924828,
        5.1715345,
        4.6572061,
        5.1715345,
        4.8924828,
        4.6572061,
        5.1715345,
        4.8924828,
        4.6572061
      ),
      logPCI = c(
        4.230186,
        4.1826606,
        4.2312036,
        4.230186,
        4.1826606,
        4.2312036,
        4.230186,
        4.1826606,
        4.2312036,
        4.230186,
        4.1826606,
        4.2312036,
        4.1066027,
        4.0960097,
        4.0707345,
        4.0960097,
        4.1066027,
        4.0707345,
        4.0960097,
        4.1066027,
        4.0707345
      ),
      loglabour3 = c(
        8.9138956,
        8.7382259,
        9.1257057,
        8.9138956,
        8.7382259,
        9.1257057,
        8.9138956,
        8.7382259,
        9.1257057,
        8.9138956,
        8.7382259,
        9.1257057,
        8.9457035,
        8.8061895,
        8.6069441,
        8.8061895,
        8.9457035,
        8.6069441,
        8.8061895,
        8.9457035,
        8.6069441
      ),
      logunem1 = c(
        5.857933,
        5.2470241,
        5.2983174,
        5.857933,
        5.2470241,
        5.2983174,
        5.857933,
        5.2470241,
        5.2983174,
        5.857933,
        5.2470241,
        5.2983174,
        5.7365723,
        5.8289456,
        5.2983174,
        5.8289456,
        5.7365723,
        5.2983174,
        5.8289456,
        5.7365723,
        5.2983174
      ),
      logroad = c(
        8.8258247,
        6.5759125,
        8.9816189,
        8.8258247,
        6.5759125,
        8.9816189,
        8.8258247,
        6.5759125,
        8.9816189,
        8.8258247,
        6.5759125,
        8.9816189,
        8.830514,
        8.5009623,
        6.4081993,
        8.5009623,
        8.830514,
        6.4081993,
        8.5009623,
        8.830514,
        6.4081993
      ),
      group = c(
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North",
        "Key_North"
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-21L),
    spec = structure(list(
      cols = list(
        firm_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                              "collector")),
        alt = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                          "collector")),
        choice = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                             "collector")),
        year_operation = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                     "collector")),
        sector = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                             "collector")),
        technology = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                                 "collector")),
        logMAinside1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                   "collector")),
        logMAoutside1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                    "collector")),
        logSAinside1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                   "collector")),
        logSAoutside1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                    "collector")),
        logseaport3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                  "collector")),
        logpop = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                             "collector")),
        logopenness = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                  "collector")),
        logPCI = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                             "collector")),
        loglabour3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                                 "collector")),
        logunem1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                               "collector")),
        logroad = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
                                              "collector")),
        group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
                                            "collector"))
      ),
      default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
                                            "collector")),
      delim = ","
    ), class = "col_spec"),
    class = c("spec_tbl_df",
              "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )``
```